# Macで踏み台経由のSFTPに対応しているクライントって無いでしょうか？

Tags: macos, ssh

Windowsとかだと、WinSCPとかで、普通に踏み台サーバー経由でファイルをやり取りできるんですが、Macってそういう機能を持っているアプリって存在しないんでしょうか？
最近だと、直越サーバーにSSHするほうが少ないので、多段SSHで当該サーバーのファイル操作したいケースばかりで困ってます。

Comment: `scp`コマンドなどではなく、GUIのアプリケーションを探しているという事ですか？

Comment: 「踏み台経由の接続」というのはWinSCPの設定だと「接続-トンネル」で設定するもののことでしょうか。

Comment: ご所望のアプリについてはわかりませんのでコメントに書きますが、sshでポートフォワーディングして FileZilla などの SFTP クライアントで localhostのフォワードした通信ポートに接続すれば踏台経由でSFTPが使えます。